# Python: unicode problem after using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode

A few days ago, I need to draw a plot by using matplotlib, since it could not display the font properly, so I

1. edited matplotlibrc file, unhashtag "font.family" and "font.serif".
2. added specific font file to ttf.
3. deleted .matplotlib file.

Then I code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Microsoft JhengHei'] 
plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
```

Now when I tried to use "to_csv" to write the dataframe into csv, there's a 
unicode problem. It ran without problem before. So I changed those 3 steps back and still have a unicode problem.

Not sure if there's any problem of my setting.

Comment: If there is a `.pyc` version of your script in the same directory, delete it. If you're using an IPython-enabled IDE such as Spyder, reset the kernel with `ctrl` + `.`

Comment: @roganjosh I use Jupyter :)

Comment: Which has an underlying IPython kernel that can be reset

Comment: @roganjosh did you mean to  delete the whole __pycache__ file?

Comment: If it's `__pycache__` we're talking about, then yes, you should delete that. If the script itself hasn't changed then it may have been "compiled" (using the term loosely) with the previous configuration.

Comment: The steps you took are related to changing the matplotlib rc params. The problem you have is a pandas `read_csv` problem. I can't see how those two relate to each other and you should consider that they might in fact just happened to appear the very same day coincidently.  Note that if you have an error, you should provide the error traceback and a [mcve] of the issue.